# Is it possible to auto fill the input of another site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that is unique to my organization that was supplied by a third party, think coupon code. What i am wondering is, is it possible for me to auto fill the required input box so that the user doesn't have to?

The site is a third party site which i don't have control over and the user would get to this site by clicking on a link on our internal intranet site. I can see this being considered a vulnerability and so prevented, but i was just curious to see if there were any options.

Comment: maybe a browser plugin.

Comment: So it's just to fill in one field on a web page? Greasmonkey would do it. It's an addon that you can use to run scripts on a web page. As for using it in an iframe you're likely to hit permissions problems.

Comment: Yeah just the one field and unfortunately I am stuck with IE.

Comment: The only other way is of the third-party allowed you do to so. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is possible depends on the site in question. Many sites will extract parts of the query string and populate form fields from them. For example, a link to https://www.google.com/?q=foo will populate the Google search box with the value "foo".

Check whether the site in question does something similar. A good way to do this might be by submitting invalid values to their form and looking for the value you submitted in the query string (this works more often than you might think).

Comment: Na it doesn't work unfortunately. What are the criteria for this to work?

Comment: @Corey it's completely up to the site in question. Many sites use a validation scheme where the client gets redirected to a resource with a query string representing the last form values sent. This frees the server from having to track this information as part of a session, and also frees the client from having to store it. This simple stateless approach, as seen in the `google.com/?q=foo` example, is pretty common.

Answer (score 0):

There's no possibility to interact between pages on different domains.

The simpliest way is to embed an iframe but browser will prevent a communication if target is on a different domain.

As it was said in the comments only reconfiguring browser (probably Webkit has an adequate overrides) or UserJS/Greasemonkey are the only solutions if you have no access to the target site.

Comment: That's not correct. Interaction can be cross domain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: Okay, but it still needs some kind of additional target site preparation: "If you do not expect to receive messages from other sites, do not add any event listeners for message events. This is a completely foolproof way to avoid security problems.". As far is I understood, we're talking about the case when the target site is completely independent.

Comment: Yes it's awkward to say the least, but you can't say "There's no possibility to interact between pages on different domains"